# Integration of Sinusoid Over Complete Period

Tags: calculus, geometry, algebraic-geometry, integration

How can be

$$\frac{1}{0.5}\int_0^1 t\sin{(2\pi t)}\ dt = \frac{-1}{\pi}$$

and inside this interval sin signal is defined, i.e. both its $+ive$ part and $-ive$ part of the wave is present.

Shouldn't be the above mentioned expression be $0$ because integration of sinusoid over complete interval is $= 0$.

Regards

Comment: Keep in mind there's a factor of $t$ in the integrand.  Btw, the "algebraic-geometry" label isn't appropriate for this question.

Comment: I know t is an integrand. Does it make any difference in answer. If yes than how?

Comment: @UmerFarooq I have typeset your mathematics.  Please verify that I edited it correctly.

Comment: correct but one thing is wrong i-e means That is

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As $\,1/0.5=2\,$ , we have by parts

$$u=t\,\,,\,u'=1\;\;\;,\;\;v'=\sin 2\pi t\,\,,\,v=-\frac{1}{2\pi}\cos 2\pi t\Longrightarrow$$

$$2\int_0^1t\sin 2\pi t\,dt=\left.-\frac{1}{\pi}t\cos 2\pi t\right|_0^1+\frac{1}{\pi}\int_0^1\cos 2\pi t\,dt=-\frac{1}{\pi}$$

as the RHS integral's clearly zero.

Answer (score 2):

Check out this [plot](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=y%20=%20t%2asin%282%2api%2at%29%20from%20t%20=%200%20to%201) of the integrand $t \sin(2 \pi t)$ from $t = 0$ to $=1$.  You can see that the "negative part" outweighs the "positive part".

Now, if you didn't have that factor of $t$ in the integrand, then the "positive part" and the "negative part" would cancel perfectly, as you see [here](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=y%20=%20sin%282%2api%2at%29%20from%20t%20=%200%20to%201).